# Closed formula for iterated derivations.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider derivations $D_1,\ldots,D_k$ of a commutative $R-$algebra $A$ and $a,b\in A$.
I am looking for a closed formula of $$D_1D_2\cdots D_k(ab).$$

It holds $$D_1(ab)=D_1(a)b+aD_2(b)$$ the next step is $$D_1D_2(ab)=D_1D_2(a)b+D_2(a)D_1(b)+D_1(a)D_2(b)+aD_1D_2(b),$$
but I did not manage to write down a general formula for arbitrary $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Write down the next two steps, i.e. $D_1D_2D_3(ab)$ and $D_1D_2D_3D_4(ab)$. Then try and work out the pattern. Once you've spotted the pattern, you can prove it by using induction on $k$. If you really can't spot the pattern, come back and ask again.

Comment: I managed to prove a formula in the case where the derivations commute with the help of the answer of Alex R.. However, I am still lacking the general case.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for the [multivariate generalization of Leibniz's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule#Higher_partial_derivatives).

Comment: This would be the solutions if the derivations commute, i.e. $D_iD_j=D_jD_i$, but in the general case the won't. I would like the have a formula for the general case.